Component re-renders and image re-loading in an image hosting app
I'm building a simple image hosting feature for my Canva clone project. The process is:
1/ Upload: User uploads an image via an  element. The image is uploaded to Amazon S3 using a PUT presigned URL, and the image key (specifically, its name) is stored in a serverless database.
2/ Display: To display the images, I retrieve the image keys from the database, generate GET presigned URLs, and display the images by using  component from Nextjs.
I'm keeping the S3 bucket private for security reasons, so each image request involves generating a presigned URL. However, this feels complex, and I wonder if there’s a more efficient way to manage this while still keeping the bucket private. Should I consider making the bucket public if only authenticated users can upload and view their images?
Additionally, I'm facing an issue where images reload every time the component re-renders (specifically, when user upload a new image or I am switching between different menu and return to the upload menu, the component re-renders). I'd like to prevent this, similar to how Canva handles its uploads, where images load only once and persist in the upload menu.
Here's a simplified version of my implementation:
const FileUpload: React.FC = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState<File[]>([]);
    const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
    const [s3Url, setS3Url] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const { user } = useUser();

    const { data, refetch } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['media', user?.id],
        queryFn: () => FetchImageKey(user!.id),
        enabled: !!user,
    });//get the images when the component renders to display existing image in the database

    const getImgURLFromKey = async (key: string) => {
        const res = await fetch(`/api/upload/get?key=${key}`);
        const { url } = await res.json();
        if (url) setS3Url((prev) => [...prev, url]);
    }; //get GET presignedURL from the image's key

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            const dbUrls = data.data.map((image) => image.url);
            dbUrls.forEach(getImgFromUrl);
        }
    }, [data]); //when data changes (user upload new image), for each image key from database, generate corresponding presigned URL to get the url to display the image
    

    const handleFileUpload = async (event: FormEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (uploading || selectedFiles.length === 0) return;
        setUploading(true);

        for (const file of selectedFiles) {
            const fileName = `${v4()}-${file.name}`;
            const putRes = await fetch('/api/upload/put', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ fileName }),
            });
            const { url: putUrl } = await putRes.json();

            if (putUrl) {
                const uploadRes = await fetch(putUrl, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    body: file,
                });
                if (uploadRes.ok) mutation.mutate({ user_id: user!.id, key: fileName });
            }
        }
        setUploading(false);
        refetch(); //re-run the useQuery sequence to show the newly uploaded image
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Upload Media</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleFileUpload}>
                <input type="file" multiple onChange={(e) => setSelectedFiles(Array.from(e.target.files!))} />
                <Button type="submit">Upload</Button>
            </form>
            {uploading && <div>Uploading...</div>}
            <div className="flex flex-wrap">
                {s3Url.map((url, i) => (
                    <Image key={i} src={url} width={400} height={400} alt="uploaded image" />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

I really think that the initial fetch for images is the cause for the images re-loading when the component re-render but I don't know how to fix.
Questions:
1/ Is there a more efficient way to handle private S3 buckets and presigned URLs for this use case?
2/ How can I prevent images from reloading every time the component re-renders, similar to how Canva manages it? Also prevent the component rerender when user upload a new image?
Thanks in advance for any insights!
